# Unable to depend on jquery from plugin

Tags: browserify, browserify-shim

so im currently using Browserify on a larger project but keep getting 'jQuery is not defined' from Jquery Validation, even when its shimmed. I use other jquery plugins aswell (but only this one is a headache), as its the only one actually being installed by NPM. According to their documentation it should be able to handle it, even jquery works, just not the plugin.

http://requirebin.com/?gist=d60e92be0904fe44cf17

Here is an example of the problem scaled down.

(I can edit an browser field in package.json to point to the file and it will work, but that seems like a counter intuitive way of usage)

Answer (score 0):

This happens because jQuery exports `$`, but not the `jQuery` variable. You can make it work by explicitly assigning $ to it:

`window.jQuery = $;`

or in your require:

`const jQuery = $ = require('jquery');`